# The Items navigation design

Tags: css

Can you help me to achieve this style for items of the navigation menu while respecting the width of each 'li' element

Design image

[image]
My attempt:

```
 .nav_list ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
color: #4d4d4d;
border-right: 2px solid #c79c60;
padding-right: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
display: inline-block;
height: 12px;
line-height: 11px;
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi, SO isn't a place where you get free job done. You can get help for issues you have in code you have. So please make an attempt to make you menu item and come back when you hit an issue.

Comment: Honestly, I did some try, but I do not succeed

Comment: Great! Then share that and explain what you don't manage

Comment: the tricky part is how to create the triangle and the border in the same blocks

Comment: we can do the trcick like this: background:url(line.png) bottom right no-repeat; but I want create the style with a pure css code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a triangle on `:hover` to the `:before` :pseudo-element and use `calc(50% - 5px)`(`5px` is the `width` of the triangle) to position the triangle in the center.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://s25.postimg.org/b6q25p4p7/black_thread.png) repeat black;
}
.nav-container {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  maring: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 67px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #C79C60;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C79C60;
}
.menu-item:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #C79C60;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="menu-item">HOME</div>
      <div class="menu-item">ABOUT US</div>
      <div class="menu-item">LOCATIONS</div>
      <div class="menu-item">SERVICES</div>
      <div class="menu-item">CONTACT US</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's works fine with some modifications ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to use absolute positioned pseudo element with horizontal auto-alignment.
If you need the triangle appears not only in hover state just remove `:hover` from CSS-selector.

```css
.b-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.b-nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c59b62;
}
.b-nav-item__label {
  font: 300 1em/1.2 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c59b62;
}
.b-nav-item:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: auto;

  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #c59b62;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-nav-item">
  <span class="b-nav-item__label">Home</span>
  <a href="#" class="b-link"></a>
</div>
<div class="b-nav-item">
  <span class="b-nav-item__label">Home Sweet Home</span>
  <a href="#" class="b-link"></a>
</div>
```

You can find live demo at http://codepen.io/kdzuin/pen/JodaQL